# Angular sync http call with underscore?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

This is my code:

```
$scope.updatePosts = function() {
  Posts.getIdsFromServer('http://localhost/postIds')
  .then(function(ids) {
    _.each(ids, function(id) {
      Posts.getByIdFromDb(id)
      .then(function(p) {
        if(p) {
          if(p.enabled) {
            Posts.getFromServer('http://localhost/post/' + id)
            .then(function(post) {
              Posts.update(post);
            })
          }
        } else {
          Posts.getFromServer('http://localhost/post/' + id)
          .then(function(post) {
            Posts.insert(post);
          })
        }
      });
    });
  }, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
};
```

This code breaks because of `_.each`

I searched SO and found this:

```
function processCoolStuff(coolStuffs) {
  return $q.all(_.map(coolStuffs, makeStuffCooler));
}
processCoolStuff(…).then(showAllMyCoolStuff);
```

But I cannot make it work, becasue I have too many async functions.

And I can get like 10000 posts and 10000 http calls, if I can use above method, will it consume a lot of memory?

How to solve it?

Comment: This feels more like a backend than a frontend problem. If you have to make tens of thousands of server calls in a single function, you're doing something wrong in the server end.

Comment: at first I just send all posts in a single call, but data size is too big, it fails quite often

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never had such a problem, but instead of `_.each`, use [`angular.forEach`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)

```
angular.forEach(ids, function(id, index, list) {}
```